# Bot Framework Composer - How to get access to dialog code files created by Composer fool

Tags: frameworks, bots

I am pretty new to this tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/introduction
and just trying to explore its capabilities after I heard about in in Build conference last week.

I tried to update echo-bot that came in as a template and wondering about following questions

1. What language does this tool use to create bots conversations? C#
   SDK or JS BF SDK?
2. How can I get access to code files (.js,.cs) dialog files? So if I
   need to modify something we can use VS code later if needed.

Basically I'm trying to understand if we can use this solution to create Bots (dialogs and conversational components etc ) and, later on update code using IDE like VS code to just integrate API's, business logic so finally we get fully functional bot.